# Image upload to media library fails. Folder won't create, database insert fail, XAMPP Windows

Tags: uploads, media

**Environment:**
The WordPress site is on my local laptop, 4.9.6.
Windows 10, XAMPP installation, PHP 7.

The procedure works fine on the remote production server with LAMP.

**Problem:**
I'm trying to upload a new logo to the media library. The file *seems* to start to upload, but then I get the error message with the red vertical stripe on the left side,

> revised logo.png
>
> Could not insert post into the database

When I look in the uploads folder, the new month folder ("5" for May) hasn't been created, so the file wasn't uploaded, either.

Not sure where I need to start on this. The error message says database, but since the file was never uploaded, it seems like a file problem.

**It Now Works:**

I don't know why the WP Migrate tool exports SQL that doesn't set the ID columns of my WP tables to auto increment. In my case, setting wp_posts and wp_postmeta ID fields to auto increment, using PhpMyAdmin, was the last procedure I did that resulted in the media library being able to insert new images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setting wp_posts ID field and wp_postmeta meta ID field to auto increment, using PhpMyAdmin.    SOLVED MY PROBLEM